# Not able establish connection to a website in android Studio

Tags: android

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nni3T.png)

This includes Asyn class for connectiing to the server and returning the webpage to the app
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GMRyn.png)
this includes Class's object and its calling

I am trying to get the scource code of the webpage in my app but it is either taking too long to return the sorce code or it fails to establis connection between the website and application